# Django admin action with extra input

Tags: django

Im wondering if it would be possible for admin to provide an extra input-field on an admin action?

I would like to make an action that duplicates a page, and changes the parent value.

```
def duplicate(self, request, queryset): 
    for obj in queryset: 

        obj.id = None
        obj.parent = #Let admin ask a question of which parent to use 
        obj.save() 

duplicate.short_description = "Duplicate selected and archive in:"


#models.py
class Page(MPTTModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    parent = TreeForeignKey('self', null=True, blank=True)    
    slug = models.SlugField(max_length=200)
```

Is this possible without to much customization?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can be helpful
[actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/contrib/admin/actions/#actions-that-provide-intermediate-pages)